# Improve Performance of Image based application

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, image

We are working on a product based application. Where their are lot images are used in it. We want to improve the performance of the application. What best practices we can used to make it faster.

We are developing this application in APS.net(C#). What features of Asp.net we can use to make it faster. Or what things we should keep in mind to make it faster.

Answer (score 0):

Optimizing images on web. I start by split it in two parts.

### Optimizing the client side

1) Cache the static media like images as max as possible. This is an example for web.config that work on IIS 7 and higher.

```
   <system.webServer >
        <staticContent >
            <clientCache cacheControlMaxAge ="8.00:00:00" 
                               cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
```

2) The correct images for the correct media

- Use gif for small images that not have degrade colors.
- Use jpg for images that use degrade.
- Use png only if you won transparent with degrade.

3) From page to page use the same image, or try to change only minimum number.

### Optimizing the server side

1) Cache the automatic creation of the images by making real files on the disk. So do not always make thubnails, make one thubnail, save it to the disk and give this url to the html page. All the next request must know that the thumbnail all ready exist and just give this url

2) The parameters that change the quality and the size of the image are:

```
g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
```

also the size of the Jpeg can change using the SaveAsJpeg function:

```
SaveAsJpeg(outputImage, TheFileNameTosaveIt, GetQualityForSave());
```

### Closing

There are many other tricks to optimizing the images that you can find here and there, on books, and on web.

Comment: I suggest looking at http://imageresizing.net/ if you're doing server-side image work. It's far too easy to have memory leaks running System.Drawing on the server, especially if you don't have a Win/C++ background. The .NET GC does NOT work on System.Drawing.

Comment: @Aristos Thanks for the detailed explanation.It's nice info.:)

Comment: Hi @Aristos in Closing you tried to mention some link. I think you forgot to mention them ("There are many other tricks to optimizing the images that you can find **here and there**, on books, and on web.")

Comment: @VSoni I mean that if you look at the internet, there are always some idea, like loading the image after user try to see it. This is something that you decide if its feet to you. Like that idea there are many more but I do not have links to show, just search on internet and see what they do or suggest.